# REST calculateroute want to supply arrival time to determine when to depart

Tags: rest, here-api

I'm working with the Here Maps REST API and wanting to get a departure time based on a needed arrival time. Basically I would supply the arrival argument and not the departure and the calculate departure time as arrive time - travel time returned.
For example I need to be at a destination at 10:00 am. If calculateroute query returns travel time to arrive at destination at 10:00 am of 45 minutes then I would need to leave by 9:15 am.
The API has an arrival property for calculateroute but has a note that it can only be used with publicTransportTimeTable mode. My mode is truck. Is there any way to accomplish this withe current version of the API?

Answer (score 0):

Arrival time is supported only for public Transport as of now. But soon you will be able to do it for other modes as well.

> https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=YOUR-APP-ID&app_code=YOUR-APP-CODE&waypoint0=geo!51.512,-0.111&waypoint1=geo!51.519,-0.074&combineChange=true&mode=fastest;publicTransportTimeTable&arrival=2018-10-09T12:44:56